# Android Kotlin class reified issue

Tags: android, kotlin

When I want to get int value from sharedpreferences I was getting the `UnsupportedOperationException` But I show from logcat, this class is `Int`. What's wrong?

```
operator inline fun <reified T : Any> get(@XMLS xml: String, @KEYS key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T {
    Timber.d("${T::class} + $xml + $key + $defaultValue")
    return when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getShared(xml)?.getString(key, defaultValue as? String ?: "") as? T ?: "" as T
        Int::class -> {
            Timber.d("not triggered") //<<
            getShared(xml)?.getInt(key, defaultValue as? Int ?: -1) as? T ?: -1 as T
        }
        Boolean::class -> getShared(xml)?.getBoolean(key, defaultValue as? Boolean == true) as? T ?: true as T
        Float::class -> getShared(xml)?.getFloat(key, defaultValue as? Float ?: -1f) as? T ?: -1f as T
        Long::class -> getShared(xml)?.getLong(key, defaultValue as? Long ?: -1) as? T ?: -1 as T
        else -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("unknown class!")
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
class kotlin.Int + application_data + Ver + null
```

Comment: Since you are declaring `T` as any subclass of `Any` and you just use the `T` to check for the class, why don't you just accept the value as `Any` type rather than a generic type and check for the class using `is`?

Comment: I would rather split this function into multiple functions since not much of the code is shared between types anyway (even default values are different), and this would add compile-time safety as a bonus.

Comment: Another problem is that this function is inline, so for every place in your code where you'll read a value from preferences using it, the compiler will replace the array access with the full function body including the switch case, which is not efficient at all.

Comment: yes but reified type need inline keywords otherwise ide given an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is failing because `Int::class` is the primitive `int` while `T::class` is the boxed type `java.lang.Integer`. The `KClass` for both of them looks like `kotlin.Int` so it's hard to tell the difference.

This works despite looking a bit odd:

```
when (T::class) {
    Int::class, Integer::class ->
}
```

(I left `Int` in there for clarity, even though it will never trigger.)